# Solution Build Fails with no error when using a string variable in Linq Where clause

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a solution that builds.  I'm now using Visual Studio 2022.  But when I add this Linq statement, it fails to build, but shows no error.

Like this - this is the bottom left area of Visual Studio:

[image: How I know the build fails with no error]

```
    Dim playlistName as String = "blablabla"
    Dim objPlaylist = (From p In Playlists
                       Where p.Name = playlistName
                       Select p).FirstOrDefault()
```

Edit: I've now found the resolution and posted the answer.  Everything below here is further detail about my project, but that had no bearing on what the source of the issue was in the end.  Read as FYI only.

---

Playlists is a Property of type `System.Collections.ICollection`
It contains Playlist objects.  I've shown the definition of these at the end of this post, below.

It still doesn't build if I change Playlists to be a `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(Of Playlist)`, or `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Playlist)`

I found that if I change the Where clause to `Where p.Name = "temp"` then it will build!  Also if I hardcode a playlist name that exists, the query will successfully find that playlist object.

The problem happens whether I use Name or Path in the Where clause.  In both cases, an explicit string in the Where clause works, and a string variable fails to build.

So it won't build because I'm using a variable in the Where clause of the Linq statement, and gives no build error to say why.

So what's wrong with using a variable in the Where clause???  And if it's wrong, why won't it give me an error when it fails to build so I can have a clue!

**More things I'm trying, and updates...**

Of course Clean Solution and Rebuild all, and exit and re-open Visual Studio.

I've added a reference to System.Data.Linq.

I've added Imports System.Linq, but it tells me it's unnecessary.

I've tried using .FirstOrDefault directly, however it still doesn't build.

```
    Dim playlistName As String = "blablabla"
    Dim oPlaylist = TestPlaylists.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.Name = playlistName)
```

I tried opening a new solution to test this specific thing in isolation, however I'm only seeing (out of support) versions of .Net Framework.  I'm going to upgrade some plumbing first.  Going to upgrade to the latest Visual Studio and see if it persists.  Ack!  It's still there in VS 2022.

Attaching the definition of the Playlists property, and the Playlist class (at the bottom of the post).

Now trying to target different (higher) framework versions, and will try again in a new solution after that.

I got to the point where it worked in a clean solution, even with Playlists being a Property, and the ViewModel being a NotificationObject, just like in the original project.  And the same piece of code would work in the clean solution, but fail to build in the problem solution.  Then I stumbled upon the root issue.

**More code snippets**

Playlists Property

```
        Private _playlists As System.Collections.ICollection
        Public Property Playlists() As System.Collections.ICollection
            Get
                Return _playlists
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As System.Collections.ICollection)
                _playlists = value
                RaisePropertyChanged("Playlists")
            End Set
        End Property
```

Playlist class

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class Playlist
    Inherits SSUtil.CustomObjects.WPF.NotificationObject

    Public Path As String  ' path to the playlist on disk (relative to prefix)
    Public Songs As New System.Collections.SortedList(New CaseInsensitiveComparer)  ' list of songs in this playlist; just list of strings that index into main ColSongs
    Public HasChanged As Boolean
    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
        Get
            ' Just the name of the playlist, e.g. Metal.m3u
            Return JustName(Path)
        End Get
    End Property
    ... some more functions
End Class
```

Comment: How are you trying to build the solution? Is there a [mre]?

Comment: I just simplified it a bit - it fails to build outside the For Each loop, so I took that out of the question.  I'm building in Visual Studio 2019 with Ctrl+Shift+B

Comment: What type is Playlists ? Why you don't use [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-firstordefault-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean))-0)) directly? `Playlists.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name = playlistName)`

Comment: @AdamSilenko, I don't know how to use lambda syntax in VB.Net.  It's not accepting it, and it's changing => to >=.  the Select syntax is more intuitive to me and it should work.  I mentioned that Playlists is of type `System.Collections.ICollection`

Comment: If you change `p.Name = playlistName` to `p.Path = "temp"` it compiles? Then maybe you should try `p.Path = playlistName`. And how do you know the build fails when the compiler "shows no error"? There must be *some* error, so don't hold it back.

Comment: Sorry, usually i write in c# :). Playlists.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.Name == playlistName)

Comment: @DocBrown, I've added a screenshot of how I know it fails to build, but shows no errors.  Also Playlist has both .Name and .Path, but both fail to build the same way if I use the varialbe in the Where clause, and succeed if I use a hardcoded string.

Comment: @AdamSilenko, thanks for the correct syntax.  I updated the question - it's the same result.  However, using `Playlists.FirstOrDefault` uncovered that ICollection doesn't have FirstOrDefault.  To use it directly I had to change the colleciton to `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(Of Playlist)`.  But still doesn't matter.  It still will only build with a hardcoded string.

Comment: Based on everyone's thoughts so far, this should work, but it's not.  I'm starting to suspect deeper issues like the fact that I upgraded to Windows 11 recently, I could upgrade Visual Studio, and I could target newer version of the framework.  Things like that...  Thanks for helping this far!

Comment: Please also show the `Playlist` type. Or better, as asked above: try to provide a [mre] so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @GertArnold, ok let me add my entire Playlist class as well as the Playlists property.  Then I'll work on reproducing in a new solution now that I have the latest Visual Studio.

Comment: So it could also be an error in `JustName(Path)`. Not seeing an exception suggests a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: It could, except the issue happens whether I use Name or Path in the Where clause.  Name calls JustName, but Path is just a string, and still doesn't work.  I have the simple case working in a new solution now, so I'm slowly adding elements of complexity to see where it breaks down.  Thanks for all input so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, so I found the offender.  It had nothing to do with Linq, although that's when the problem manifested.

I had an `On Error Resume Next` at the top of the function where I added the Linq query.  That's the extent of it.  If that line is commented out, there is no problem, and the solution builds successfully, and the Linq query works.  With that line, build fails with no error.

A second thing I discovered later is when I got another failed build with no errors, I checked the Output window.  And there it showed the error that was being encountered!  Fiding that saved me the pain I had to go through the first time around when my build was failing with no errors.

I hope this helps someone working with an old project in the future.  Cheers!

Comment: Ah, so that's why C# developers (like me) didn't have a clue! I hope you'll replace all these statements by try/catch.

Comment: Yes, I've decided to do a deeper refactoring on the whole thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If Playlists is System.Collections.ICollection then you need [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7.2) it to `IColection<Playlist>`

```
Public Class X
    Private playlistName As String

    Public Sub OnClick()
        Dim objPlaylist As Playlist

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(playlistName) Then
            Console.WriteLine("playlistName is empty")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            objPlaylist = Playlists.Cast(Of Playlist).FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.Name = playlistName)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That also fails to build unless I use a hardcoded string.  Also no ; at the end.  LOL  Of course I removed it.

Comment: c# :), from where you get playlistName ?

Comment: In the program, it comes from a list that the user clicks on.  However, if this darn thing won't compile even with the string defined in the most simple manner on the line before, then it's probably not the source of the playlistName that's the root cause here.  Clearly this should work.  I'm starting to suspect deeper issues like the fact that I upgraded to Windows 11 recently, I could upgrade Visual Studio, and I could target newer version of the framework.  Things like that...  Thanks for helping.